# A query about API to handle DHCP discovery/offer messages

Tags: c#, c++, dhcp

I am writing a network-based program that needs to discover DHCP servers if existing on the same network segment.
Specifically, i need to broadcast the "DHCP Discover" message so that my program knows if there is some server through "DHCP Offer" response message.
i researched about this topic, and found some thread that indicates this to be impossible in Windows. However, i wish to know your thoughts about the issue .
The language to be used is C++, C#, or Java.

i appreciate your help.

Comment: It isn't impossible, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224877/querying-a-dhcp-server-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why would it be impossible in Windows? If it were, DHCP wouldn't be available for Windows machines.. which obviously is not the case.

Comment: Is your question whether it's possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? Open a raw socket, pump messages, receive responses.

Comment: raw socket is said to be not possible in Windows due to security reasons in the OS

Comment: Run as administrator then...

Comment: thanks you Alex , Greg ,Drew and Miky for helping ,it works ........using raw socket(as you say Alex it needs administrator privileges) .