# how to query DHCP from C# (Managed code)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dhcp

Is there any `Class/Namespace` I can use to query `DHCP server` and get the list of all the`Reserved IPs`?

Comment: Please have a look at the answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224877/querying-a-dhcp-server-in-c-sharp

Comment: @zatixiz : I did not ask the question without searching google

Comment: Either that, or make a powershell module to use the cmdlets 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590751(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: One of my current positions is network administrator, and DHCP is something I've never considered handling/querying in C# so it's quite interesting to me as well. I will have a closer look at it and let you know if I come up with something!

Comment: Does the DHCP protocol allow you to query for all the reserved addresses? I thought you could only ask to lease and release an IP address.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: PowerShell cmdlets for DHCP (Windows 2012) allows to do that if you have proper rights

Answer (score 1):

> As per my knowledge and bit of search online, I guess there isn't any .NET namespace which you can use to achieve what you want. But then for that you can use **Win32 Native API**. Please refer *[this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363376(VS.85).aspx)*. And to get some idea of the use of this API, you can find some code samples *[here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dhcpsapi/DhcpEnumSubnetClients.html)*.

You can find more useful information on this from the following web links:

1. **[Querying Windows DHCP Server With C#](http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/dhcpcsharp.htm)**
2. **[IPInterfaceProperties.DhcpServerAddresses Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dhcpserveraddresses(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Hope this answer helps and adds somethings valuable to your quest !

**Edit:** This solution which I mentioned is Win32 APIs which is basically unmanaged code. I just noticed your question heading has **(Managed Code)**. And this solution probably might not be new to you. Still I am keeping it here as an answer to other solution seekers. And to **[Call Native Functions from Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx)**.

Comment: better option is to call PowerShell cmdlets and execute them on the server rather than calling Win32 APIs. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a better option.